# cross-domain jquery 1.6.2 ajax call is trying to call from same domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain

I have an api set up on another domain, domain B (api.domainb.com), and want to make a call to it from domain A (www.domaina.com). However, when I do a call from domain A to domain B via jquery ajax, jquery ends up trying to call www.domaina.com/api.domainb.com which obviously will return an error. Here is the relevant javascript code

```
    $.ajax(
      url: 'http://api.domainb.com',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: {hello: 'world'}, 
      crossDomain: true,
      success: function(data){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data))
      }, 
      error: function(error){
        alert(JSON.stringify(error))
      });
```

Eventually, the code in domain A and domain B will be on the same domain, but for now, I need to make a cross-domain call. Any suggestions as to how to make this work?

Comment: in the original version of this question, I had url as url: 'api.domainb.com'. It was suggested that I should change it to 'http://api.domainb.com'. The code in the original version of the question has been updated to reflect this. I tried adding the 'http://' but there was no change - I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make cross-domain calls; browsers simply do not allow it in general. However, the reason you're seeing the behavior you describe is that your URL is missing the "http://" prefix.

There are some things you can do with [fairly new HTML5 APIs](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/cors/raw-file/tip/Overview.html) to sort-of "get permission" to do cross-domain calls.

*edit* @Dan points out correctly that while XMLHttpRequest (what people usually call "ajax") won't do cross-domain stuff (CORS aside), it's possible to leverage the fact that `<script>` tags can reference other domains  in order to put together a service.  The server-side code has to be different, however.  (That's usually called "[JSONP](http://json-p.org/)".)

Comment: I'm not an expert in it, but IIRC you can use JSONP to get around the restriction, as long as the server-side is prepared to cooperate. Behind the scenes it works by using `script` tags instead of an XHR.

Comment: Yes that's true, but of course then it's not really XHR :-)  I'll clarify the answer however.  Thanks!

Comment: Right but I think the point behind jQuery abstracting that difference in its `ajax` call is that XHR and JSONP really achieve the same thing. Arguing definitions is tricky of course, but I never considered "AJAX" to mean only XHR.

Comment: I agree 100%.  It's tricky to balance "common parlance" meanings with stricter definitions, the latter being of limited use I guess.

Comment: I tried adding the 'http' (now reflected in the code in the question) but am having the same issue as before.

Comment: It's still trying to make requests to "www.domaina.com/api.domainb.com"?  That seems very unlikely. Is the service on "domainb" implemented such that a JSONP request will work? Have you checked the debugging tools to see what the actual HTTP transaction looks like?

Answer (score 2):

You're just missing the protocol so that the Ajax call knows it's a different domain and not a relative URL. Try using `url: 'http://api.domainb.com'`.